# Fortran segmentation fault when deallocating a coarray component of a derived type (bug?)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-coarrays

I get a segfault when trying to deallocate a coarray component of a derived type. This happens after I assign one instance of the type to another. The minimal example is as follows:

```
program mytest

   implicit none
   type notmytype
      real, allocatable :: coarr(:)[:]
   end type notmytype

   type(notmytype) :: nmt, nmt2

   allocate(nmt%coarr(10)[*])

   nmt2 = nmt
   deallocate(nmt2%coarr)

end program mytest
```

I compile this with: `ifort -coarray -coarray-num-images=16 test.f90 -o test.exe`

I can successfully query `size(nmt2%coarr)` before the deallocate statement. Any thoughts? Is this a bug? The ifort version is: ifort (IFORT) 19.0.3.199 20190206

Comment: Plesse use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Also check the descriptions of the tags you add. Coarrays are a Fortran 2008+ feature.

Comment: Your compiler version is old. Very old given how modern features you want to use. Try a recent version, it's free.

Comment: Героям слава, thanks for the comment, do you believe the old compiler IS the source of the problem? If that is the case I will need to bring this issue up at my workplace. Also, I am new to this site, so please let me know what my next steps should be with regard to this question.

Comment: I would have to try it, but it may very well be. Your code should be good enough as a reproducer, I  just did not have any time for that.